# Nuxt 3 Static site "_payload.json" not found (404) due to wrong route on request

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

**Overview of the problem**

I have set up the following routes

- /books

  - [slug]

    - summary
    - character analysis
    - quotes

I run the command `yarn generate` and all the files are generated without errors. But when I navigate to any route under */books/[slug]/* I get an error that the *_payload.json* was not found.

And the problem, with why it's not found is that the request route is */summary/_payload.json* not */books/[slug]/summary/_payload.json*. The file is generated, but not loaded correctly.

Inside nuxt.config.ts I haven't overwritten any route rules.

[image: Screenshot of the console log errors]

[image: I am using the following depenencies]

Comment: Hi, how do you preview the generated app? Also, do you maybe have a [repro]?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
For the live environment, I am using render.com and deploying it as a static app "yarn; yarn generate".
For local env I am using "yarn generate" and then "npx serve .output/public". 

For both environments, I preview the app using Google Chrome in Guest mode (no extensions).

Comment: Do you have the error with `/books/[slug]/summary` too? Tried adding a `index.vue`?

Comment: Yes, the error comes up when visiting any route under /books/[slug]/ except index.vue.  I have set up it as such that books is dir, [slug] is dir and under that dir I have index.vue, quotes.vue, etc.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm running into the exact same issue unfortunately

Comment: No, unfortunately not.
You can disable the [payloadExtraction](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/experimental-features#payloadextraction) feature, but for my app, it's necessary so it doesn't have to request the API right away.